# CardView not showing on my device

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-cardview

I created an android app with a dashboard Designed with Cardviews. When i run it on the virtual device or on my tablet, it displays the cards. But doesn't display them on non Tablets Devices. Did someone faced this issue and how could be solved?

Comment: studio has the view hierarchy tool built in now so you can see where your view is and if it's there what is it's state. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html

Comment: are you using a constraint layout,if yes please set the constraints

Comment: On which api device you are testing?

Comment: Can you add some code to show how you tryed it?

Answer (score 0):

It may cause by Hardware acceleration is not enabled. Please enable this property in application field by using this line in your manifest.xml file and try again:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

Comment: Thanks Let me Try it

Comment: How is it going?